# How to add legened to geom_vline?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-vline

I have a dataframe (**df_new**) that looks something like this:

```
date<- c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05")
A <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
B <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
  
df_new <- data.frame(date, A, B)
df_new$date <- as.Date(df_new$date)
```

I am using the following code to plot values **A** and **B**.

```
ggplot(data = df_new, aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = A, colour = "Value A")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = B, colour = "Value B"))+
  labs(title = 'A & B Distribution',
       x = '',
       y = 'Value Count',
       color = " ") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-01-03")), linetype=4)+
  theme(text=element_text(size=13),panel.spacing.x=unit(0.6, "lines"),
        panel.spacing.y=unit(1, "lines"))
```

It is giving me the plot as desired [image] except that I would like to add a legend of *geom_vline* under Value B where I have manually drawn a black line.

Any guidance please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually set a legend with color using `scale_color_manual`. You name the `color` of `vline` black which you can assign as a value in the legend by `"black"="black"`. This can be manually changed to whatever you want. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
ggplot(data = df_new, aes(x = date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = A, colour = "Value A")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = B, colour = "Value B"))+
  labs(title = 'A & B Distribution',
       x = '',
       y = 'Value Count',
       color = " ") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-01-03")), linetype=4, color = "black")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=13),panel.spacing.x=unit(0.6, "lines"),
        panel.spacing.y=unit(1, "lines")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Value A" = "red", "Value B" = "blue", "black" = "black"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am copy+pasting your exact code, running it, but the black line in legend just would not appear :( any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: @AneesBaqir, That is really strange. It should actually work, maybe you accidentally copied it wrong? Maybe clear your environment and try it in a new file?

Comment: There is something wrong with my environment, because I've been trying similar solutions for so long and they didn't work. Now I tested it on rstudio cloud, and it is giving the output as yours. Thank you :)

Comment: I found the problem, the ggplot2 verison was 3.3.3 previously on my system, I updated it to latest version and it did the work. 
One final question please, how to make the line in legend same as in the plot?